# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I tried copying a bunch of custom plugins into my `C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext` folder.

But when I try to open `C:\Projects\centaurjmeter\src\test\unittests\mytree\loadtest.mytree.jmx`, I get this error:

```
Problem loading XML from:'C:\Projects\centaurjmeter\src\test\unittests\mytree\unittest.mytree.common.jmx'. 
Cause:
NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class au.com.mycompany.jmeter.reporters.TimingListener

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
cause-message       : Could not initialize class au.com.mycompany.jmeter.reporters.TimingListener
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:98)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/au.com.mycompany.jmeter.reporters.TimingListener
line number         : 197
version             : 5.3
-------------------------------
```

I'm using JMeter 5.3.

This is the content of my `C:\Projects\centaurjmeter\pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>centaurjmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- No need to run deploy lifecycle -->
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>

        <!-- No need to create a JAR -->
        <jar.skipIfEmpty>true</jar.skipIfEmpty>
        <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>

        <!-- Specify which JMX to run by default -->
        <testname>unittests</testname>
        <!-- Run in perftest env unless overridden using -Denv -->
        <env>perf</env>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompany</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompanyproject-visualstudio.com-maven</id>
            <!-- <id>mycompany</id> -->
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/maven/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies are used for regression load tests. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for AMQP JMS messaging -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid/qpid-jms-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_2.0_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid/proton-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>proton-j</artifactId>
            <version>0.30.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-codec-http -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-kqueue</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-resolver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-handler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-common -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-buffer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.31.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.blazemeter/jmeter-plugins-wsc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-wsc</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for Invoice Genius -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>perfsignalr</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>microsoft.aspnet.signalr</groupId>
            <artifactId>signalr-client-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for signalr-client-sdk and timinglistener -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for websocket samplers for SignalR in mytree (https://github.com/ptrd/jmeter-websocket-samplers) -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.luminis.jmeter/jmeter-websocket-samplers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.luminis.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-websocket-samplers</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Record timing and transaction data in JSON format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>timinglistener</artifactId>
            <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log directly to Sumologic HTTP endpoint -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sumologic.plugins.log4j/sumologic-log4j2-appender -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sumologic.plugins.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>sumologic-log4j2-appender</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sumologic.plugins.http/sumologic-http-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sumologic.plugins.http</groupId>
            <artifactId>sumologic-http-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Exclude PDF and GIFTS files in the unittests -->
                    <exclude>data/*/gifts/**/*.gifts</exclude>
                    <exclude>data/*/qif/**/*.qif</exclude>
                    <exclude>data/*/invoices/**/*.pdf</exclude>
                    <exclude>data/*/invoices/**/*.png</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the content of `C:\Projects\mycompany-jmeter-plugins\timinglistener\pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mycompany-jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
        <groupId>au.com.mycompany</groupId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>timinglistener</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting indicates that the jar containing `au.com.mycompany.jmeter.reporters.TimingListener` class is not present under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so make sure it's there

1. Plugins themselves should go to "lib/ext" folder
2. Plugins dependencies should go to "lib" folder (unless they're ["fat jars"](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html))
3. **JMeter restart is needed to pick up the libraries**
4. If you run JMeter via maven you need to [specify the dependencies a little bit differently](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
5. If you're using [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3) for test execution you should ramp-up `ApacheJMeter_core` and `ApacheJMeter_components` to version 5.3 as well.

Comment: I have C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext\timinglistener-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar which contains C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\timinglistener-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar\au\com\mycompany\jmeter\reporters\TimingListener.class, TimingListenerBeanInfo.class and TimingListenerResources.properties.
I also copied timinglistener-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib in case it had to be there and restarted JMeter but didn't work.

Comment: I will eventually be running JMeter via Maven but for now I just want to open the .jmx files in the JMeter GUI.
How do I update ApacheJMeter_core and ApacheJMeter_components? I can't find anything about updating them on Google.
I have a folder called .m2\repository\org\apache\jmeter\ApacheJMeter_core which contains folders called 2.13, 3.1, 3.3 and 4.0. I also have ApacheJMeter_components.jar and ApacheJMeter_core.jar in C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext. I can download the 5.3 .jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/5.3 but where do I put this file?

Comment: I've checked C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\jmeter.properties to see if user.classpath or plugin_dependency_paths have defined a different folder but they are both commented out